# Publish Feed Story Using Facebook API

Tags: iphone, facebook

I want to publish information to user's wall from iphone application. I am using the Facebook SDK for iphone. I found in the documentation that I should use FBStreamDialog but this loads a form to the user and s/he write the story to be published, I don't want this behavior. I want to publish user actions at my application and user just needs to click share button, then the application should fill a template story and publish.

I found this use case was available before with FBFeedDialog but this is not supported via the API now.

Any suggestions, what I should do?

//Modified

here's an example for David's solution:

```
NSString *att = @"{\"name\":\"i\'m bursting with joy\",\"caption\": \"User rated the lolcat 5 stars\", \"description\": \"a funny looking cat\"}";
NSDictionary *attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:att forKey:@"attachment"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.stream.publish" params:attachment];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@"stream.publish"

Comment: Do u have an example?

I read the wiki, http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.publish, but FB SDK for iphone doesn't have a corresponding class for calling facebookAPI.

Comment: thanks David, I added an example at the original post for better looking.

Comment: Glad I could head you in the right direction. FBs APIs can be daunting.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code occur error "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"

Comment: Yes, user must give you permission before you can publish any feeds, check this http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_iPhone_SDK#Getting_Extended_Permissions.

and the FBConnect project have the code for asking user to give the permission.